# Backbone Views as CommonJS modules

Tags: backbone.js, commonjs, browserify

I'm trying to get my head around using CommonJS modules within a Backbone application, so I have a skeleton Backbone View defined in `/views/categories/edit.js`:

```
app.Views.quoteCategoriesEdit = app.Ui.ModalView.extend({

    className: '',

    template: JST["templates/quotes/categories/quote-categories-edit.html"],
    events: {
        'click [data-key="save"]': 'save',
        'click [data-key="cancel"]': 'cancel'
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        var that = this;
        _.bindAll(this, 'save', 'cancel');
        app.Collections.quotesCategories.on('change add', function () {
            that.remove();
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        // boilerplate render code
        return this;
    }

});
```

If someone could show me how I can convert this into a CommonJS module to be used with Browserify, then I would be very grateful and it'd really help me understand how I go about modularising the rest of the application! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//once you get things into folders/files, this path may change
//but for now I'm assuming all your views will live in the same directory 
var ModalView = require('./modal-view');

var QuoteCategoriesEdit = ModalView.extend({

    className: '',

    template: JST["templates/quotes/categories/quote-categories-edit.html"],
    events: {
        'click [data-key="save"]': 'save',
        'click [data-key="cancel"]': 'cancel'
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        var that = this;
        _.bindAll(this, 'save', 'cancel');
        app.Collections.quotesCategories.on('change add', function () {
            that.remove();
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        // boilerplate render code
        return this;
    }

});
//Simplest convention is just 1-class-per-module
//Just export the constructor function
module.exports = QuoteCategoriesEdit;
```

Follow-up question from the comments:

> Very much appreciate this! How would you approach: app.Collections.quotesCategories as I house everything under the app namespace? Do I just require the Collection itself?

So the idea of an "app" namespace is the opposite of being modular/commonjs/browserify/requirejs. You don't need an `app` object anymore. Any module that needs to create a new instance of this collection would just do `var QuotesCategories = require('app/collections/quotes-categories');` and that is all. No more globals or namespace objects. Mostly your views will get the models/collections they need in their constructor function `options`. Most of your models will get created by calling `fetch` on a collection, and most of your collections will be instantiated by your router.

Oh, and yes in this specific example it's probably best if non-view code creates the collection and passes it to the view via the constructor `options.collection` parameter. However, if you decided yes you really wanted your view to instantiate the collection, it wouldn't come from the `app` global namespace object, it would just come from a `require` call as you describe in your comment.

Comment: Very much appreciate this! How would you approach: `app.Collections.quotesCategories` as I house everything under the `app` namespace? Do I just `require` the Collection itself?

Comment: Very very very helpful, thanks very much! There wasn't as much about Backbone and CommonJS when I googled around, more Backbone and AMD!